# WPF Design Layout vs Compiled Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm getting differences between the design in VS2010 and the layout when compiled. See the images bellow:

**Design View**
[image]

**Compiled**
[image]

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596436/wpf-design-time-vs-run-time-style-differences-with-triggers) and I don't seem to be able to pick anything out that will help me. Why does this happen?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="iAdvert_Desktop.TemplateDesigner"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="622" Width="610" AllowsTransparency="False" Opacity="1" Background="White" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Pages/BaseStyle.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Height="281" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Background="#FF383838" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="canvas1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseMove="canvas1_PreviewMouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="canvas1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="45,30,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="5"></Canvas>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" DataContext="{Binding}" HeadersVisibility="Column" Height="143" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#ccc" Margin="45,356,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#ccc" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" Background="#FFF6F6F6" Width="500">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Pages/DataGridStyle.xaml" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Source="/iAdvert-Desktop;component/Images/icons/delete.png" Height="12" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"></Image>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="0.5*" Binding="{Binding Path=TemplateCellID}" Header="ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellWidth}" Header="Width"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellHeight}" Header="Height"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellTop}" Header="Top"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellLeft}" Header="Left"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Add Cell" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" Margin="470,317,43,243" />
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,504,271,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextDescription}" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,504,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Template Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Save Template" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="450,505,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="button2_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

BaseStyle:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="TextHeader" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextDescription" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

DataGridStyle:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsControl.AlternationCount" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF333333" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#333" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#f1f1f1" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#f9f9f9" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#ccc" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="20" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CenterCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CenterTextCell" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the problem xaml.

Comment: Without any xaml this is going to be hard to diagnose.

Comment: As a tip on trying to locate the source of the problem, turn on `ShowGridLines` on your Grid. You'll be able to identify *which* components have moved, the first step in working aroudn the problem.

Comment: @bevan, where can this be done?

Comment: Go to the Grid that forms the base of your form, and set ShowGridLines to true, either in the property editor or in your xaml. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines.aspx

Comment: I don't think that will help because @Prisoner is just using the grid as a simple container and not using rows & columns to lay out the controls (the layout is done with margins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that this works better.  It looks the same in the designer and when you run it.

All I have done is remove your margins and add rows/columns to your grid (and a stackpanel for the template label/textbox).

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <RowDefinition Height="301"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF383838" ></Canvas>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add Cell" Height="23" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,10" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding}" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#ccc" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#ccc" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" Background="#FFF6F6F6" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">                            
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="0.5*" Binding="{Binding Path=TemplateCellID}" Header="ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellWidth}" Header="Width"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellHeight}" Header="Height"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellTop}" Header="Top"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCell}" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=CellLeft}" Header="Left"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextDescription}" Height="26" Name="textBlock1" Text="Template Name" />
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Height="26" Name="textBox1" Width="178" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Save Template" Height="23" Width="95"  />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: This is a much better way of doing the layout. Can't believe I haven't been doing it the whole time. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

The simplistic answer to this is that the engine used to render the display in Visual Studio has a bug in it that impacts rendering of your application. You would need to post your XAML code for others to check but it may be worth opening your XAML in Expression Blend to see if the rendering is closer to what you see in the compiled version.